# Heroku SSL "certificate is only valid for the following names: *.herokuapp.com, herokuapp.com"

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm trying to setup a Geotrust SSL certificate for my Heroku app using the SSL Endpoint addon and the instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint.

I generated my public key from my private key using:

```
openssl rsa -in server.orig.key -out server.key
```

and added to the heroku certs:

```
heroku certs:add server.crt server.key
```

Everything seemed to be fine. heroku certs listed the corrected information only with `Trusted = false` for my certificate.

If I go to `https://tokyo-2121.herokussl.com` the browser says:

```
You attempted to reach tokyo-2121.herokussl.com,
but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as www.mydomain.com.
```

As expected with the certificate apparently identifying the correct domain, but When I set up the CNAME to the given `tokyo-2121.herokussl.com` and visit my subdomain the browser says:

```
www.mydomain.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for the following names:
*.herokuapp.com , herokuapp.com
```

If I run curl `-kv https://www.mydomain.com`

I get: `subjectAltName does not match www.mydomain.com`

Comment: I was wondering because of the `Trusted = false` result if this was an issue with Intermediate certificates and how that might be rectified?

Comment: No, it's not an intermediate certificate issue.  It's a straight name mismatch.  I would go over the steps again, and check to make sure the DNS resolves correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will repeat the process... but it seems strange that the heroku certs information is correct and the certificate seems correct at: https://tokyo-2121.herokussl.com

Answer (score 1):

I tried the process again, it seems my mistake was in this step:

```
openssl rsa -in server.orig.key -out server.key
```

I already had the private key in server.orig.key and didn't need to generate it. I just needed  to attache my Geotrust .crt and .key files to the heroku ssl endpoint.

Comment: Heroku allowed you to submit a cert that didn't match the key?!